# How to set "/*" path to capture all routes in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Like in `ExpressJS`, `app.get("/*")` works for all routes.

My code -

```py
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/*')
def user_lost():
    return "Sorry You Are Lost !"
```

I tried it but the webpage result shows `{"detail":"Not Found"}`
How can I do the **same** in **`FastApi`**?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please see [ask].

Comment: I tried, Still It Didn't Work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `/{full_path}` to capture all routes in one path (See [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/routing/#path-parameters)).

```py
@app.route("/{full_path:path}")
async def capture_routes(request: Request, full_path: str):
    ...
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me with the newest FastAPI version

Comment: Weird, it worked for me when I replaced route with get

Comment: in the latest versions this has changed from `app.route` to `app.api_route` https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/819#issuecomment-569222914

Answer (score 3):

I edited Yagiz's code to:

```
@app.get("/{full_path:path}")
async def capture_routes(request: Request, full_path: str):
   ...
```

Comment: Please show the line of code where the problem is. Be mor eprecise.

Comment: Import `Request` class from fastapi.
Use:
`from fastapi import Request`

Answer (score 0):

Best explained in https://sureshdsk.dev/how-to-implement-catch-all-route-in-fast-api

The only additional comment is;

if you want to mix catch-all and handle certain paths like /hello or /api .. make sure that catch all method definition is at the last .... order of route definitions matter